# NHibernate Initialization in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, s#arp-architecture

I am using Asp.Net MVC and NHibernate.

Some of my Global.asax file is shown below:

```
 public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        // The WebSessionStorage must be created during the Init() to tie in HttpApplication events
        webSessionStorage = new WebSessionStorage(this);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Due to issues on IIS7, the NHibernate initialization cannot reside in Init() but
    /// must only be called once.  Consequently, we invoke a thread-safe singleton class to 
    /// ensure it's only initialized once.
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //the following code sets up the NHibernate Session Factory
        NHibernateInitializer.Instance().InitializeNHibernateOnce(
            () => InitializeNHibernateSession());
    }
```

Whenever the AppPool recycles the next request is taking a while to execute due to it having to wait for the NHibernateSessionFactory to initialise. After that everything is fine until the next app pool recycle.

Now I'd like to move the initialization into the Application_Start method, so that when the pool recycles, the restart does the heavy lifting PRIOR to the next request coming in. However the comment "Due to issues on IIS7" which comes from S#arp architecture made me realise it's not that simple.

I did find an article: http://scottsdalewebstudio.com/blog/mvc/mvc-sharp-iis7-nhibernate/ which suggests that setting IIS to use "Classic Mode" fixes it - is this the only way?